# Crypt Decrypt java Object ID by annotation using RESTEasy

Tags: java, encryption, annotations, resteasy

I'm developing a frontend application that calls java web services using RestEasy Maven plugin. My need is to crypt/decrypt the objects ID during the server/client  calls and vice versa. I was wondering if anyone know any Maven plugins that, given a particular Annotations on an IDs of the java Class,  automatically encrypt(before return response to frontend)/decrypt(before web service method was called) those fields.

I tried to read interceptors and stuff like this to find some solutions

I expect that some fields (marked by java annotations) could be crypted before server send response to client , and decrypted before Web Services are executed

Answer (score 0):

have you tried [jsypt](http://www.jasypt.org/) ?, Its good for keeping encrypted properties in property file, I believe it can be used in your case as well.